# AttributeError: 'loginUser' object has no attribute 'var'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to limit characters, but I find this error. Someone to help?
And would it be able to limit characters from type A to D and from 0 to 9?
In the initializer I already got it, now I want to try out the initializer, but I could not understand this error, I'm new at it.

```
class loginUser:
    def __init__(self, window, master=None):   
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("System F2T")

        #Definicoes de fonte p/ o layout de login
        self.fonteTitulo = ("Arial","10","bold")
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "10")

        #Labels e campos de texto do sistema de login
        self.userLabel = Label(text="Digite seu usuário:", font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#000",fg="#FFF").place(x=27,y=60)
        self.user = Entry(textvariable=self.var, font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
        self.user.place(x=140,y=60,width=110)

        self.senhaLabel = Label(text="Digite sua senha:", font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#000",fg="#FFF").place(x=29,y=90)
        self.senha = Entry(textvariable=self.var2, font=self.fontePadrao,show="*",bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
        self.senha.place(x=140,y=90,width=110)

        self.max_user = 1
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.trace("w", loginUser.limiteUsuario)
        self.max_senha = 4
        self.var2 = StringVar()
        self.var2.trace("w", loginUser.limiteSenha)

    def limiteUsuario(self,*args):
        u = self.var.get()
        if len(u) == 1 and not 65<=ord(u)<=68: # you can also use *if not u in "ABCD"*
            self.var.set("")
        elif len(u) > 1:
            if not 65<=ord(u[-1])<=68: # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
                self.var.set(u[:-1])
            else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
                self.var.set(u[:self.max_user])

    def limiteSenha(self,*args):
        s = self.var2.get()
        if len(s) > 4:
            if not s[-1].isdigit(): # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
                self.var2.set(s[:-1])
            else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
                self.var2.set(s[:self.max_senha])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root['bg'] = "#000"
    loginUser(root)
    #Tamanho da janela
    root.geometry("330x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: look at when you define `self.var` and when you use `self.var`.

Comment: Hmm, I still do not understand, I put self, in the others, I edited the code again here in question, but the error keeps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan pointed out, your `self.var` is being set as a text variable before it has been created. Simply shuffle where you defined them to fix.

```
class loginUser:
    def __init__(self, window, master=None):   
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("System F2T")
        ...
        self.var = StringVar() #create the var first before you assign them
        self.var2 = StringVar()
        #Labels e campos de texto do sistema de login
        self.user = Entry(textvariable=self.var, font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
        ...
        self.senha = Entry(textvariable=self.var2, font=self.fontePadrao,show="*",bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
```

On how to limit your the input from A-D, you can add an additional check in your `limiteUsuario` method. Note that I also fixed the potential errors from your class method.

```
def limiteUsuario(self,*args):
    u = self.var.get()
    if len(u) == 1 and not 65<=ord(u)<=68: # you can also use *if not u in "ABCD"*
        self.var.set("")
    elif len(u) > 1:
        if not 65<=ord(u[-1])<=68: # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
            self.var.set(u[:-1])
        else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
            self.var.set(u[:self.max_user])
```

You can use the similar logic for number 0-9.

Comment: Hmm, I still do not understand, I put self, in the others, I edited the code again here in question, but the error keeps.

Comment: The error is obvious - in `self.user` you set `self.var` as textvariable. Has `self.var` been defined yet?

Comment: Right, and how do I define in textvariable, something to do with ""?

Comment: Just move the definition of both `self.var` and `self.var2` to the top.

Comment: Also you should change `self.var.trace("w", loginUser.limiteUsuario)` to `self.var.trace("w", self.limiteUsuario)`.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I caught the little time python and programming itself, so I do not have much wisdom yet, but when it says top, should of where the self.var? outside of the entry ()?

Comment: Anywhere before you define the `entry`. I added a simplified sample to the answer.